# Can Bran Stark control dragons?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire, dragons

In the third season of Game Of Thrones, we saw scenes showing that Bran can control [Summer](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Summer_%28direwolf%29) and [Hodor](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Hodor), since he is a [warg](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Warg).

In [S2E03: What Is Dead May Never Die](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Is_Dead_May_Never_Die) Bran says to [Luwin](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Luwin):

> [Old Nan](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Old_Nan) used to tell me stories about magical people who could live
>   inside stags, **birds**, wolves...

I think dragons are not birds exactly because from [this](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon) page:

> Dragons, **like a bird**, tend to imprint on whoever is present when they
>   hatch, regarding that person as their parent.

So, can Bran control dragons?

Comment: I suspect Bran warging into a dragon is a major plot point to come. That said, at this point we can only speculate, so this is probably not a good question for this website.

Comment: Not necessarily, maybe it can be re-written to be less speculative? Especially if you have read all the books. And maybe I'm mistaken and GRRM has said something about this in his blog, in which case the question is answerable.

Comment: Or, for that matter, could Bran warg into Daenerys & control all three dragons?

Comment: That quote from the wiki that says dragons "tend to imprint" is completely unsupported in the books, and it would be silly if someone did make such a claim in the tv-show.

Comment: Before Bran, I always believed *Huh, Dragons. Game Set Match Khaleesi*. But the moment I knew Bran was a warg the first thought that came to my mind was *Huh Khaleesi, you are in a show tonight darling*

Comment: @TLP I didn't read the books but as you said, dragons are always mentioned as _special animals_ by GRRM and Tolkein.

Comment: @SonerGönül I would take the words from that particular wiki well salted, as it were. It seems like the people writing there are making stuff up freely, without quoting their source.

Comment: @RobertF, I thought, that Bran managed to control Hodor, cause Hodor's mind is too weak and rather convenient to control.

Comment: An ordinary warg might not be able to control a dragon but a greenseer surely could.

Comment: @GinoPane: as per season six’s “Hold the Door”, Hodor’s mind may be weak because Bran managed to control him.

Comment: now this question becomes super meaningful

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer would be "No He probably can't". We can't answer this from Show canon because show has never mentioned an encounter between Wargs and Dragons. So we have to see the history in books.

### Examples of Wargs encountering dragons

Only example of when wargs came face to face with dragons is when King [Jaehaerys I Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jaehaerys_I_Targaryen) and his consort [Queen Alysanne the Good](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Alysanne_Targaryen)<sup>1</sup> flew north to help the Night's Watch and defeated a host of wildlings, wargs and giants at wall. Pictured Queen Alysanne on Silverwing at the Wall, during the campaign<sup>2</sup>:

[image]

No warg managed to control [Vermithor](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Vermithor) (Mount of Jaehaerys) or [Silverwing](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Silverwing) (mount of Alysanne). This is implied because if a warg had managed that, it would have been a huge event and must have been reported in chronicles of watch or some other record.

This would have also probably caused death of the dragon rider targeted by the warg since the logical move on part of the warg would be to make the dragon throw his/her rider off to the ground. But since nothing like this is reported, we can assume it never happened.

If trained and experienced wildling Wargs could not control dragons, we can assume untrained and green Bran can't either.

### Claiming/Controlling a dragon

Still We do not know if skin changers can slip into dragons. Some may say Dragonlords of Valyria might have used some different sort of skin-changing for riding dragons because after a dragon was claimed by a rider, they both shared a bond and became aware of each other (e.g. [Dreamfyre](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dreamfyre) broke her chains when her rider Queen [Helaena Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Helaena_Targaryen) jumped from Red Keep to die). But that would be a weak argument. Bond with a dragon seems to be way different.

But anyhow, we know it for Blood-magic, which allowed Dragonlords to claim dragons. Everything the Valyrians accomplished is attributed to their knowledge of blood magic.

Dragons are not like horses, to be ridden by any man who desires. They only serve the person who is their rider e.g. Prince [Joffrey Velaryon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Joffrey_Velaryon) was thrown to his death by [Syrax](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Syrax) who was his mother [Rhaenyra Targaryen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaenyra_Targaryen)'s mount. Aegon the Conqueror flew Balerion but he never dared to mount dragons of his sisters; Vhagar and Meraxes. No Dragon rider has ever claimed two dragons.

All three of Daenerys's dragons were unclaimed previously. Daenerys has now claimed Drogon so he is unlikely to allow another rider until Daenerys lives. Rhaegel and Viserion are however up for taking.

If Bran was trained and knew how to slip into a dragon, we don't know what would have happened. Historically, only people with Valyrian blood have ridden a dragon. But anyhow, Bran does not share a bond with the dragons unlike his wolf (Daenerys did, her dragons could feel her rage & her being in danger and act accordingly). So it is unlikely he could control a dragon. But since as the new Green-seer, Bran would have more powers than most Wargs, we do not know for sure if he can or cannot control a dragon.

---

<sub>1. [The tower](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Queenscrown) in which Jojen and Bran were hiding was actually named in memory of Queen Alysanne</sub>

<sub>2. Art by [Emile Denis](http://trishkell.deviantart.com/)</sub>

Comment: Only one skinchanger in a thousand is born a greenseer ... of course he can.

Comment: @TheMathemagician How exactly do you infer the "Of course he can" part? That sounds quite sure.

Comment: Dragons don't behave that differently from other animals and wargs possess animals. Varamyr didn't have any prior bond with his shadowcat or bear so that's unnecessary. We know Bran is a greenseer which is an exceptional form of warg. Therefore Bran should be able to warg into dragons. It's the opposite position - that dragons are somehow immune from warging - that needs special justification.

Comment: @TheMathemagician The immunity of dragons is based on speculation from a past event that did happen(RE: King Jaehaerys and army of Wildlings). Do you have any reference where a warg or a greenseer managed to take a dragon? Also, **Still We do not know if skin changers can slip into dragons. Some may say Dragonlords of Valyria might have used some different sort of skin-changing for riding dragons**

Comment: Nice answer. My 2 cents on the skin-changing King Jaeharys' dragon: was there a powerful enough skin changer to warg a dragon present at this encounter? I guess we don't know. My gut feeling is that it would be possible but might not happen. On the subject of different types of skin-changing, can we include the shows resurrection of Viserion as skin-changing?

Comment: @josh We don't even know how to quantify the power of Skinchangers. I believe the power is same, it's the skill which varies. As for Viserion, I believe we can't. Viserion appears to have been resurrected using necromancy, not Skin-changing. Of course there is a theory going around in show circles that the Others control their minions using skin-changing. GRRM has however refused to comment on it. So maybe, maybe, we could consider that skinchanging

Comment: @josh You can see another one of my [answers here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/167842/54887), if you are interested in that topic

Comment: probably it's a good time to rethink this answer

Comment: @Yevhen People who have provided an answer from Showverse can do what they like. My answer is based on the books. Besides, even in the show IIRC, Bran hasn't been able to control dragons

Answer (score 13):

The Valyrian Freehold was led by dragonlords, the Targaryens being the last surviving dynasty. It's quite possible that they were also wargs (and Daenerys is a warg) and that was the means by which they tamed their dragons. From what I remember from the books warging can create (creates?) a bond with a certain creature and if the wargs body dies their soul lives on in the creature.

Some wargs have multiple bonds; others just one. Thus, it would not be so simple to warg in to an already bonded creature especially one as complex as a dragon. Also the only reason Bran could control Hodor is because Hodor is mentally handicapped and a higher functioning individual would resist. But otherwise I would assume warging with dragons is possible just not as simple as you might assume. I do believe one of the Starks will end up bonding with a dragon. But that's just speculation on my part.

Comment: Daenerys has never shown any signs of being a warg.

Comment: Neither did Robb or Rickon. And they're both confirmed by GRRM as wargs.

Comment: Daenerys could not be a warg bcause she doesnt have warg blood bran rickon robb and jon all have the blood of the first men in them

Comment: @tywinstark - Warg blood is not confined to the Starks. We've seen other wargs after all. If the Targaryen dragon lords were indeed wargs, then it would probably be hereditary. The novella "The Princess and the Queen" sheds a bit of light on this. Showing that people who are Targaryens (or descended from them) had a better chance at taming dragons.

Comment: Having read GRRM's The World of Ice and Fire, it makes no mention of any Valyrian dragon lords being wargs, therefore it can be assumed that they aren't. Valyrian dragonlords do indeed have a bond with their dragons, however as the books and tv series highlight, Daenary's has a difficult time controlling her dragons even though shes their "mother". If she was a warg surely it be a lot easier for her to maintain control over them.

Comment: @JATerroba There are several passages linking the behavior of Rickon and ShaggyDog quite clearly hinting he's a warg.

Comment: @TheMathemagician Ok, change Rickon for Sansa and my statement holds true.

Comment: "mentally handicapped" can be replaced with "heavily traumatized by his posessor"

Comment: @JATerroba I would say Robb and Rickon also showed signs. They could command and control their wolves. So, wargs!

Comment: Of course Robb warged. https://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/2n6fts/spoilers_all_what_is_the_evidence_of_robb_being_a/cmasz8z

Answer (score 2):

Although the books make no mention of a historical link between the Starks and dragons, the fact that Bran is a warg would suggest that he could in theory control dragons. This said I agree with Solomon that it's probably a lot harder for him to achieve this feat than it was for him to control Hodor, due to the fact that dragons are a more complex, volatile and wild beast. However with his new found power IT may allow him to control any beast or person he now desires.