# What is the range of a Warg? (Distance of Warging)

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In **Season 3 episode 2 , Dark wings, Dark Words** the Character Orell has his eyes rolled back and an Eagle is circling above and Mance says to Jon Snow that he is a "warg". This is the first time we are shown a Warg. OK, by now we all know what a Warg is and in previous episodes Bran also is Warging, although he does not know it yet and we are not show what he is doing.

When Bran is Warging he seems to go pretty far away from his actual body while he is in the wolves consciousness. Orwell seems to Warg into an Eagle and when asked by Mance where he was (had been) and he states that he was at the `The Fist of the First Men` and saw dead `Crows`.

I don't know how far away from the position that they were standing at was from the `The Fist of the First Men`but, is there anything in the books or the show that sates reasonably how far they can Warg?

I also understand that not all Wargs are created equal, as Bran seems to be an extremly powerful Warg as he is able to take over a humans consciousnesses.

Comment: Relevant: [How did Bran manage to warg into correct wolf](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129474/how-did-bran-warg-into-the-correct-wolf-to-help-jon-in-the-rains-of-castamere/129562#129562), See the paragraph with heading **Distance between Ghost and Bran** in my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the books, Arya has demonstrated ability to warg into Nymeria (albeit unconciously in a dream) across continents. (Dance of Dragons Chapter 45 The Blind Girl).

So it appears there is no range limit.

Comment: Correct, Also Jon snow warged into Ghost while Ranging with Qhorin Halfhand. He was miles away yet Jon managed to slip into his skin and observe the wildling Army in Frostfangs